# Production deployment steps for flyway for DB2 table REORG call

Tags: db2, flyway

In one of my migration files on my development box I have this DB2 request:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE COST_RULES.LOW_DLL_EXCEP');
```

This call seems to be needed for a subsequent ALTER on a column done in a subsequent migration. In the past the devops person manually executed the call to reorg on the test database, but I'd like to put it into the migration so it gets done automatically.

If I add this, it will change the checksum on the migration file, causing a flyway issue when the deployment happens. What Flyway steps should be taken before the deployed job works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a table has had certain kinds of alterations, or a certain number of alterations, Db2 can put the table into `reorg pending` status.

When the table is NOT in `reorg_pending` condition, it is not necessary to preform reorg at this time solely for the purposes of migrations.

Consider changing your migration to make reorg conditional, and also consider online reorg if the table type is compatible.

You can use view `SYSIBMADM.ADMINTABINFO` and check `REORG_PENDING='Y'` for your table to decide whether or not to perform a reorg. You can use an SQL PL anonymous block to run the conditional logic and conditional reorg.

You can use the `INPLACE` option for reorg (and related options) if the table is suitable for online reorg.

You could also use an entirely separate migration, to test if any tables in your schema(s) of interest are in `reorg_pending` state, and take appropriate action at that time, including checking the table type to see if an online reorg is appropriate. Such a migration would be re-runnable. It would have its own checksum.

Comment: I'll just add that you should put reorg in a separate migration file because REORG will commit the current transaction. I.e. if something bad happens after reorg you'll end up in limbo (some things have already happened next time you run your migration)

Answer (score 0):

If you're correcting a script that has already been run, and you don't want it to run again (but you need the change either to reflect a change done manually on production or to spin up copies faithfully) then run `flyway repair` once the change is made - that will recalculate the checksums to align with the current state of the scripts.

Comment: I don't know how to fully respond, because I think you partially answered my question as well as the one above. Thank you. If it's only one migration file that changed, what's the consequence of just updating the checksum in the table? I've run flyway repair only to find it didn't repair.